# WUBI doesn't work with 32 bit windows

Tags: installation, 12.10, wubi, windows-7, 32-bit

Well as the title says I can't use Wubi with 32 bit windows, it produces an error. Is there any fix?

Comment: Did you mean: **I** can't use the Windows installer? What error are you getting? I'd advise just burning a CD or USB.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please help us help you. What kind of error are you experiencing? Could you edit your question with the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I have no ideas , but :

teoria says that 32bit win can host a 64 bit ubuntu , but i suppose that this make some mess .
try to use a 32 bit ubuntu version .

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) guide, you can install Ubuntu using Wubi either pre-download the appropriate 32 bit ISO manually and place it in the same folder as Wubi.exe or start Wubi from the command prompt with the

```
"--32bit"
```

argument.

To modify arguments without using the command prompt, right-click Wubi.exe and select "Create Shortcut". Then right-click the shortcut, select Properties, and modify the Target line, for example:

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Desktop\wubi.exe" --32bit
```